# Sorting Subsets of a Sorted Vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm trying to figure out the best way to sort an array under multiple criteria. I want to sort an array, then sort a subset of that array if they were equal under the first criteria.

Example:

Say we have the data: `{ ("cat", 2), ("dog", 4), ("cat", 1), ("dog", 3) }`

We sort this first according to alphabetical order of the string:

`{ ("cat", 2), ("cat", 1), ("dog", 4), ("dog", 3) }`

Then we sort the two subsets (set of cats and the set of dogs) in increasing order of their numbers:

`{ ("cat", 1), ("cat", 2), ("dog", 3), ("dog", 4) }`

Also, I'm using a recursive quicksort method that has the following header:

```
void quickSort(vector<Type*>, int left, int right)
```

where left and right are the bounding indices by which the vector should be sorted.

Should I add code to the sorting method itself or should i call the sorting method again somehow?

Comment: You should think a little bit by yourself. The help of others won't help you to tackle the other problems by yourself. I recommend you not to use StackOverflow for solving your homework.

Comment: This isn't a homework assignment, teaching myself, FYI. And I have thought by myself. I've figured it out, I'm searching for the "best" way as I stated. I'm looking to optimize right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you want a custom comparator to sort with.

```
struct Foo {
  std::string name;
  int count;
  struct Less {
    bool operator()(const Foo &lhs, const Foo &rhs) const {
      if ((int c = lhs.name.compare(rhs.name)) != 0)
        return c < 0;
      return lhs.count < rhs.count;
    }
  };
};

std::vector<Foo> foos;
// ...
std::sort(foos.begin(), foos.end(), Foo::Less());
```

If you can't just use a single custom operator, you can use a stable sort.

As pointed out by Mark, `std::sort` is **not** a stable sort.  Instead you would need to use `std::stable_sort`.

You want to sort them independently in order of increasing importance.  So, you sort by numbers and then by the string.

```
struct Foo {
  std::string name;
  int count;
  struct NameLess {
    bool operator()(const Foo &lhs, const Foo &rhs) const {
      return lhs.name.compare(rhs.name) < 0;
    }
  };
  struct CountLess {
    bool operator()(const Foo &lhs, const Foo &rhs) const {
      return lhs.count < rhs.count;
    }
  };
};

std::vector<Foo> foos;
// ...
std::stable_sort(foos.begin(), foos.end(), Foo::CountLess());
std::stable_sort(foos.begin(), foos.end(), Foo::NameLess());
```

You would prefer the first obviously, but the latter can come in handy for keeping combinatorial and/or run-time configurable algorithms simplistic.

For reference:

[cplusplus.com C++ : Reference : STL Algorithms : stable_sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/)

[cplusplus.com C++ : Reference : STL Algorithms : sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

Comment: If you were to use multiple sorts, would you sort in order of increasing importance? Like: sort(nums); sort(strings); ... ; sort(moreImportantCriteria); ?

Comment: `std::sort` isn't stable so if you use multiple sorts there are *no guarantees* about what if any effect previous sorts would have on the final results.

Comment: @Howie Yes, that what I tried to communicate.  That is different than using a single comparator version.

Answer (score 2):

If you store your data as a `vector<pair<string, int> >` then  you can just use `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());` and it will just work because `pair`'s `operator<` will already use both parts of the object to do the sorting.

Answer (score 2):

you could overload your < operator then you could use vector.unique() and then vector.sort()

Answer (score 2):

In your case you need a custom comparator cause you are mixing data Types you couldn't compare your standart comparator could only compare same data Types and doesn't know with which criteria you would sort.